# Asus x99 Deluxe run sli in slots 1 and 3

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to setup SLI with two 980Ti's. I am using an Asus x99 Deluxe mother board with a 5820k and I have the switch on the mobo set to two way SLI. The manual says that I should use slots 1 and 4 but when using 4 I cannot plug in my USB 3.0 connector to the motherboard. the CPU supports 28 lane so I know that one card would be 16x and the other 8x. if I go into the bios to change slot 3 to an 8x slot, 3 does not show up. I am on the latest bios. I know slot three works because I can see the GPU in slot 3 in the OS which is windows 10.
I have seen other forum where people say it is possible but none explain how.

Comment: Your motherboard is limited in the SLI configuration it supports.  You will have to make a decision SLI or USB 3.0 or get a slimmer graphics card.

Comment: Or since 980's are not wuite cheap. A slimmer USB 3 cable or an cheap USB 3 (or 3.1 gen 2) PCI-e card.